# How to use AudioServicesRemoveSystemSoundCompletion Callback

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, playback

I am trying to play two different files in a queue. One is an intro track and another is a main track.

My Method to setup music playback

```
-(void)musicPlayBack:(CFStringRef )soundName{

    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle
                                              , (CFStringRef) soundName, CFSTR ("mp3"), NULL);
    SystemSoundID soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion(soundID, NULL, NULL, FinishedSoundPlayback, NULL);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);

}

-(void)playIntro:(NSString *)introTrackName{
    NSArray *introTracks = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"heybaby",@"dumbson",@"heybadass",
                            @"heydarling",@"heyhoney",@"madam",@"sir", nil];
    [self musicPlayBack:(__bridge CFStringRef)([introTracks objectAtIndex:2])];
}

-(void)playNotification:(NSString *)notificationTrackName{

    [self musicPlayBack:(__bridge CFStringRef)(notificationTrackName)];
}

-(void)notifyWithSound:(int)batteryCase{
    NSArray *mainSoundTracks = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ten",@"twenty",@"twentyfive",@"thirty",
                                @"fourty",@"fifty",@"sixty",@"seventy",@"seventyfive",
                                @"eigthy",@"ninty",@"hundred",nil];
    [self playIntro:@"someRandomIntro"];
    while (introFinished==NO) {
        if (introFinished==YES) {
            break;
        }
    }
    [self playNotification:[mainSoundTracks objectAtIndex:batteryCase]];


}
```

This is what i have before @implementation

```
BOOL introFinished = NO;

static void FinishedSoundPlayback(SystemSoundID  mySSID, void* data){
    introFinished = YES;
    AudioServicesRemoveSystemSoundCompletion (mySSID);
    NSLog(@"completion Callback");
}
```

The problem is FinishedSoundPlayback never gets called.

Answer (score 0):

You registered the system sound under the name "soundId" and you expect callback for "mySSID". This suppose to be the same name. BTW I do not recommend this API for playing music because of its limitation.